# ES6 fetch: How do I change the localhost port it calls?

Tags: javascript, spring, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I have a webpack-dev-server running with node.js on `:8080` serving my frontend. I have a Spring Boot MVC application running on `:8088` serving my actual backend service.

I have a login system I want to call on :8088, how would I change the permanent settings of the `fetch` function to refer to `:8088` instead of `:8080` every time the function is called?

I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
login ({commit}, authData) {
      fetch('/api/login', {
        username: authData.username,
        password: authData.password
      }, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'post',
        url: `http://localhost:8088`,
        credentials: 'include'
      }) // ... goes on
```

However, it still refers to 8080:

```
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {  }
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login"
```

Comment: u can change it from application.properties

Comment: Could you provide an example of configuring it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried to put full url in your fetch first parameter? Pretty sure `/api/login` would make the request to the current host.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8088/api/login', {
    username: authData.username,
    password: authData.password
  }, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'post',
    url: `http://localhost:8088`,
    credentials: 'include'
  })
```

Of course you need to have CORS enabled for this to work.

Comment: Then I get `message: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`

Comment: Are you sure CORS is enabled on your server application? You can find good help here: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Yes,I have configured my whole application in Spring Boot to accept CORS origin from localhost:8080. I can see, however, that the request never enters the server. But it works fine from cURL directly.